# Python plot for beginners - ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension (code inside)

Tags: python, matplotlib, plot

I'm an absolute python beginner who wants/has to programm a web grabber script to extract data from a weather forecast webpage to plot it.

i made a raw_input so that people can choose a city from where they wanna see weather details plotted, thats the relevant for the plot:

```
import os
import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
from datetime import datetime

path = "data\\"
names = os.listdir(path)

namelist=[]
for element in names:
    element = element[:-4]
    namelist.append(element)

print namelist


while True:                                                  
    nennDenOrt = raw_input("tell me the name of your city\n")
    if nennDenOrt in namelist:
        print "here's your weather: "

    temp = []
    relfeuc = []
    ns = []
    sonne = []
    timestamps = []
    with open(path + nennDenOrt + ".dat", "r") as infile:
        for line in infile:
            line = line.strip() # remove whitespaces newlines etc
            data = line.split(",")
            temp.append[2]
            relfeuc.append[3]
            ns.append[4]
            sonne.append(data[5])
            print data[0]
            actual_time = datetime.strptime(str(data[0]),"%Y-%m-%d %H-%M-%S")

            timestamps.append(actual_time)
            print data


    plt.figure(1)                # the first figure
    plt.title("Ihr Wetter für " + nennDenOrt + " von " + timestamps[0] + " bis " + timestamps[1])

    plt.subplot(221)             
    plt.plot(timestamps,temp)
    plt.xlabel('Zeit')
    plt.ylabel('°C')
```

...

the data that I use for the plots is inside the *.dat and looks like this:

2015-06-17 18-38-30,1184,12.9,68,0.0,45

2015-06-17 18-38-33,1184,12.9,68,0.0,45

2015-06-17 18-38-36,1184,12.9,68,0.0,45

2015-06-17 18-38-40,1184,12.9,68,0.0,45
...

(the time [0] will be the x-axis and the other 4 values will be each on the y-axis of 4 different plots.)

I get this error message and don't know how to solve the issue:

```
 plt.plot(timestamps,temp)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\pyplot.py", line 2987, in plot
    ret = ax.plot(*args, **kwargs)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 4137, in plot
    for line in self._get_lines(*args, **kwargs):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 317, in _grab_next_args
    for seg in self._plot_args(remaining, kwargs):
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 295, in _plot_args
    x, y = self._xy_from_xy(x, y)
  File "C:\Python27\ArcGIS10.2\lib\site-packages\matplotlib\axes.py", line 237, in _xy_from_xy
    raise ValueError("x and y must have same first dimension")
ValueError: x and y must have same first dimension
```

maybe some of you what to do? thanks a lot in advance !

Comment: just realized i really dont have a plan what im doing here. forgot to fill the other lists, which i just did:         with open(path + nennDenOrt + ".dat", "r") as infile:
            for line in infile:
                line = line.strip() # remove whitespaces newlines etc
                data = line.split(",")
                temp.append[2]
                relfeuc.append[3]
                ns.append[4]
                sonne.append(data[5]) ----- but the error messages keep coming :/

Comment: Please add the other filling parts to the question as update

Comment: `temp.append[2]` is wrong. append is a method => so you need parenthesis instead of square brackets => `temp.append(2)` or `temp.append(data[2])` ... same thing for `relfeuc.append[3]` and `ns.append[4]`

Answer (score 0):

You are using this code -

```
plt.plot(timestamps,temp)
```

But nowhere in the code are you giving any value for `temp` variable, do you mean to use `sonne` variable instead? Like -

```
plt.plot(timestamps,sonne)
```

The below code is also wrong -

```
temp.append[2]
relfeuc.append[3]
ns.append[4]
```

I do not think `temp` or `relfeuc` have a property like `append` that is subscriptable. You need to do -

```
temp.append(data[2])
relfeuc.append(data[3])
ns.append(data[4])
```

Comment: sorry, that is what i just realised after posting (edited the code several times and posted the wrong version), im giving values for temp, sonne, ns,.. like all the lists , in the comment. but still the code is not working. with all the values added, the new ErrorMessage is: line 34, in <module>
    temp.append[2]
TypeError: 'builtin_function_or_method' object has no attribute '__getitem__' --do you know what this means? thanks for your comment !

Comment: Can you please paste the code in the quesiton , by editing it , by clicking the `edit` link to the bottom of the question?

Comment: @goatastic see my comment above about this TypeError